# API or method to convert gesture to text in android

Tags: android, android-layout, gesture-recognition, motion-detection, android-gesture

I am developing an application which will take gestures and convert those gestures to according text and store them in database. I want to know if there is any Android API or method for this task.

Comment: You mean a gesture that's being made by touching the screen ?

Comment: yes, gesture using finger or pen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `GestureDetector` that generates `String` when a gesture is detected.

For example use `OnGestureListener` callbacks :

```
// From inside some Context (View, Activity, ...)
GestureDectector detector = new GestureDetector(this, new OnGestureListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        gestureDetected("FLING"); // 'gestureDetected' is then a callback to invoke on 'conversion of a gesture into a string'
    }
});
```

Then `MotionEvent` have to be 'forwarded' to the `GestureDetector`, for example by overriding `View.onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` :

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return detector.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: would that GestureDetector  would return the string it will detect in gesture?

Comment: No, id doesn't work like this : it already detects basic gestures like 'fling', then a callback is invoked (see `OnGestureListener`). You can then generate the appropriate string inside the callback, see my edit above

Comment: is there any way to get gesture in text like english alphabets gestures?

Comment: Just change "FLING" to something else =) For non built-in gestures, you'll have to declare methods of your own.